# How should I tell a job that I would like to review my other offers?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

Lets say I apply to job A, B, and C. Job A calls me back next week and says they want to hire me and I am starting next week. But I have yet to hear back from job B, and C. How can I tell job A that I need a little time to review my options? For me at least, every time a job calls its almost as if they assume they are the only job I applied to.

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever watch the show Shark Tank where they review other offers, don't get another offer, and lose the first?

Is A is an offer you would take?

If A wants you to start next week that means they want someone next week.

Consider asking for an extension could go badly. 
Worst case is they revoke the offer.

Find out where you stand with B and C.
Politely contact B and C and ask them for a time frame for a decision. 
If B and C won't even give you a time frame then A is looking better.

If you do ask for more time then make it a short extension and give them a specific date that you will get back with them with your final decision.

If A responds no I need you now that is not a bad thing. 
That means they feel you can contribute immediately.

If A gives you an extension then Contact B and C and let them them know they have X days to make an offer or not.

Comment: I'll just go to add, asking A for an extension could cost you your offer with A.

Comment: @RualStorge That is what I tried to cover in the first and last paragraphs but good of you to be direct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this. You are acting based on a phone call?

In the real world, at least the white collar world, offers are WRITTEN and they have an explicit time window. If, by some bizarre omission, there is no time window in the written offer, then the time window is legally infinity.

Personally, I would never work for somebody who was so stupid as not to define a time window in their offer letter, but if you want to do so, and the guy calls you up and says "Well, are you accepting or not." just say "I am still thinking about it". After all you have an infinity amount of time to think about so why not?

Answer (score -2):

Is the job in an Employment at Will state?

If so company A could let you go without cause at any point.

If job A is good terms take it. You might like it. If B or and C call you back or do another round of interviews you can still go, but if an offer ever comes you will want to negotiate hopefully from a point of strength because things different now. You took a job and likely burn a bridge if you were to leave so soon before company can recoup their investment in you so you would need a very good incentive.

I was in a similar situation I finally got an opportunity to interview with Company C (ESPN a dream company of mine since college), but Hurricane Sandy happened and an office move happened. I had two really good offers from both A and B companies. Company A I heard really good things about, but it was contractor with no clear path to conversion and Company B never heard of, a start up. I let company A know when I interviewed I was doing an interview tour, I was told I was their first choice but they needed a commitment, they didn't want me to interview with company C. 
So I accepted company B which I was also upfront with that I had a possible job opportunity in NYC that it was a long shot that I'd take as it would require moving to NY/NJ but it was a possibility and I had to see it through.

Well in a month's time I really got to help Company B and I got to evaluate the opportunity I had to make a difference at Company B and the day to day work I was getting to do which was all latest mobile stuff. It turned out the particular ESPN gig I was being considered for was not as appealing, they wanted me to worry about the feature phones which are non smart phones that still had browsers, which meant I would be investing a year building depreciating skills. So I stuck with Company B and been there ever since.